Does an ERC database exist?
I'm searching for a database of every canonical signature a contract should implement to comply with a certain ERC. For example, to comply with ERC20 a contract should implement name(), symbol(), etc. and to comply with ERC721 it should implement X and Y...
Does anyone know if such a list / database exists?
Something like this, but with all ERCs:
{
  "ERC20": [
    "name()",
    "symbol()",
    "decimals()",
    "totalSupply()",
    "balanceOf(address)",
    "transfer(address,uint256)",
    "transferFrom(address,address,uint256)",
    "approve(address,uint256)",
    "allowance(address,address)",
    "Transfer(address,address,uint256)",
    "Approval(address,address,uint256)"
  ],
  "ERC165": [
    "supportsInterface(bytes4)"
  ],
  "ERC721": [
    "balanceOf(address)",
    "ownerOf(uint256)",
    "safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256,bytes)",
    "safeTransferFrom(address,address,uint256)",
    "transferFrom(address,address,uint256)",
    "approve(address,uint256)",
    "setApproveForAll(address,bool)",
    "getApproved(uint256)",
    "isApprovedForAll(address,address)",
    "supportsInterface(bytes4)",
    "Transfer(address,address,uint256)",
    "Approval(address,address,uint256)",
    "ApprovalForAll(address,address,bool)"
  ]
}


A single, centralized database might not exist as you described, but there are several ways to get some information from various sources and compile the same to get the required details, like:

You can get the list of all the available ERC standards from Ethereum official list of ERCs.

You can get more details about any specific ERC standard from the ERCs folder of the Ethereum official GitHub repo.

You can also get the information from the interfaces folder of the OpenZeppelin Contracts repo.


